# Rails4 and MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I installed MongoMapper according to [Installation in Rails3](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html)

but my rails' version is 4.0.1, I got the following error message

```rb
    undefined method `read_inheritable_attribute' for User:Class
```

The code of User in app/models :

```rb
    class User
        include MongoMapper::Document
        key :name,    String
    end
```

and in my controller, I called it

```rb
    user = User.new(:name=>'hello')
    user.save!
```

The whole trace

```rb
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:37:in `method_missing'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:14:in `protected_attributes'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:42:in `protected_attributes'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:47:in `filter_protected_attrs'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:30:in `assign'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:165:in `initialize'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:44:in `initialize'
mongo_mapper (0.8.6) lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/sci.rb:26:in `initialize'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `new'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `sign_in'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__349567981__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__20632434__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
D:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
D:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
D:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_inheritable_attribute` is depreciated, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259017/2128691)

There's a few things you can try -

First, update `mongo_mapper` to `0.13.0.beta2` - 0.8.6 is quite old.

You can also try including `gem 'libv8'` in your gemfile and then running `bundle install`.