# Patching enumerations_mixin gem for rails >=3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, enumeration

[enumerations_mixin gem](https://github.com/protocool/enumerations_mixin) depends on [deprecated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258735/read-inheritable-attribute-undefined-in-rails-3-2-8)

[here's the guilty line](https://github.com/protocool/enumerations_mixin/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts/enumerated.rb#L56)

what would be correct approach to patch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a lot of patching I am afraid. This method has been replaced by `class_attribute`, however it works slightly different. Previously it was enough to use `write_inheritable_attribute` to create new class param, now you need to declare it first and then assign value.

On line 17 it is using 'write_inheritable_attribute` to set those values. It should now read

```
class_attribute :"acts_enumerated_#{key}" unless respond_to? "acts_enumerated_#{key}"
self.send(:"acts_enumerated_#{key}=", options[key])
```

Then, everywhere it is using `read_inheritable_attribute(:attribute_name)` just use `self.attribute_name`.

The only problem with this is that 'read_inheritable_attribute` returned nil if attribute is not set and the approach above will throw an error. You will notice that all read methods has default value, like (line 56):

```
read_inheritable_attribute(:acts_enumerated_on_lookup_failure) || :enforce_strict_literals
```

You will need to look for all those defaults and enforce them within acts as enumerated method:

```
def acts_as_enumerated(options = {})
      valid_keys = [:conditions, :order, :on_lookup_failure]
      default_options = {<all the default values from the code>}
      options = default_options.merge options
      options.assert_valid_keys(*valid_keys)
      valid_keys.each do |key|
        write_inheritable_attribute("acts_enumerated_#{key.to_s}".to_sym, options[key]) if options.has_key? key
      end
```

However this is not a perfect design. I would probably define `class_attribute enumerated_options` within append_features method, put all the options there as a hash instead of creating class_attribute for each option. This is absolutely up to you though.

Also please notice that this gem has been written over 4 years ago, and this method might be not the only deprecated one. I am not entirely sure what this gem is supposed to do, but it might be easier to rather implement what you need rather than to use it.

Comment: I found an easy way out: http://code.whomwah.com/ruby/rubyonrails/bbclistenlive/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/inheritable_attributes.rb

Comment: Yep, that would be the easiest way, however I've never liked solutions of this kind. The framework evolves, we shouldn't force it to use old patterns as there are good reasons why they have been removed. It is ok as a temporary solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem)'s repo locally and use it in your [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) project as a path to a local gem. So specify in your **[gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile)**:

```
gem :enumerations_mixin, :path => '/local/path/to/gem'
```

When you will have the gem patched, fork it on [github](/questions/tagged/github), replace gems origin in **/local/path/to/gem/.git/config**, push your changes to your fork, and replace that line in your **[gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile)** to the follownig:

```
gem :enumerations_mixin, :github => 'your_acoount/enumerations_mixin'
```

Issue the [pull-request](/questions/tagged/pull-request) to the root repo of the gem, and when the request will be accepted, replace that line in your **[gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile)** to the follownig:

```
gem :enumerations_mixin, :github => 'protocool/enumerations_mixin'
```

When the gem will have been released the line can be replaced to:

```
gem :enumerations_mixin, '~> <new_verison>'
```

Comment: kk... rephrasing question: how to replace usage of read_inheritable_attribute? i don't really understand meaning of it.